# github file not getting committed

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub, but I have followed the steps to create a repo:

```
$ mkdir fb
$ cd fb 
$ git init 
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
$ git push origin master
```

Now when I try to make my first commit, I get the follwowing error:

```
$ git push origin master
error: Cannot access URL https://github.com/xxx/yyy/, return code 60
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/yyy'
```

I am using the latest git version. Why does GitHub throw this unusal error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you try using the SSH protocol for the git repository, e.g. `git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git`, and see if that works for you?

`$ git remote rm origin`

`$ git remote add origin git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git`

Comment: The SSH url should read `git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git`. Note the colon between `git@github.com` and the repository information. Using a `/` will result in a fatal error.

Comment: Prefer `git remote set-url`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that return error code has something to do with the SSL Certificate... I'm sorry I cannot help further.

Comment: Since this isn't an answer, but more of a suggestion in where the problem may lie, this would be more appropriate as a comment to the question.