# Pushing files to github and getting error

Tags: git

I have tried for the first time to upload files from my local computer to github.

On trying to upload them I get the error

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/name/file.git'
```

I have looked around stackoverflow for similar issues and found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461682/github-file-not-getting-committed) which I thought had answered my question. I added

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com:name/file.git
```

and nothing happend, what else do I need to add?

===EDIT===

after further looking I found that

git commit -m 'my message' would do it

This returned the message

```
5 files changed, 162 insertions(+)
```

On going to my repository nothing has been added

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Comment: When you say nothing happened you tried to push again, right? Did you get an error message? Did you put the actual name of the repo, rather than "name/file.git"?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Comment: http://try.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can not push unless you commit anything first.

You did commit. Nothing has changed - it was committed, but files stayed the same. You can push now.

Answer (score 0):

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)":

The *first* push to GitHub needs to be a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then, after making other commits, you will be able to simply "`git push`" those (no parameter required: the local master branch knows where to push)